# Node.js: Get path to app folder from within node module installed by that app

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

I have a Node.js app ( `MyGreatApp` ) that requires a node module like so:

```
// MyGreatApp/level_1/level_2/build.js

const myNpmModule = require('myNpmModule')();
```

The said node module ( `myNpmModule` ) executes the following code:

```
// MyGreatApp/node_modules/myNpmModule/index.js

const path = require('path');

module.exports = function() {
  console.log(path.parse(process.mainModule.filename).dir);
}
```

What is logged on the console is:

```
/Users/myname/myapps/MyGreatApp/level_1/level_2/
```

What I want logged on the console is:

```
/Users/myname/myapps/MyGreatApp/
```

In other words, doing `path.parse(process.mainModule.filename).dir` from within a node module will return **the path to the folder of the file that requires that module**.

But what I want to know is the **the path to the parent folder of the app that installed/uses that module**.

(note: I won't know the location of the file that will be requiring `myNpmModule` in advance..)

Answer (score 1):

I've found an npm module that does it: [app-root-path](https://github.com/inxilpro/node-app-root-path#installation)

Looks like it [does all the dirty job for you only relying on `__dirname` as a starting point](https://github.com/inxilpro/node-app-root-path/blob/master/lib/resolve.js#L22).

If anyone has a simpler/better way please post an answer :-)